# Tell the difference between mortar and grout?

Tags: tile

I had a contractor come in and lay new tile in my home. When the job was done, there were 2 or 3 tiles that were uneven and we asked the tile setter to chip out those tiles and replace them.

For those 2 or 3 tiles, I suspect (for various reasons) that the tile setter used mortar (Versabond thinset) between the replaced tile and its neighbors rather than grout.

How can I tell for sure?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question: keep em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Does the color match, and texture (sanded or non sanded)?

Answer (score 1):

Color would be one indicator, other than that in the short term there really isn't a way to tell the difference because grout and mortar are very similar the only big difference is that mortar has lime and grout does not. Over time mortar will/can show signs of efflorescence, a white chalky looking film.